# Resizing in browser developer tools ruins footer

Tags: html, css, web-inspector

I think its a bad title so if someone can suggest me a better title please tell me.

**The problem:** When I resize my webpage in the browsers developer tools it first goes good (when I make it smaller) but when I make the small part bigger again, it will go strange.

**Questions with it**:

- Can I fix this
- Is it a problem since it only happens when you first make it small and then big and I don't think people will do that in a random web page.

Could it be because it first is like this

```
block1, block2, block3{
   display: table-cell;
}
```

and then I change it

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 860px) { 
    block1{display: block;} 
    block2{display: inline-block;} 
    block3{display: inline-block;}
}
```

**Image were all 3 phases are shown**:
[image]

The last phase of the footer should look the same as the first phase of the footer.

**If needed the full html and css code off the footer**

Real HTML:

```
<div class="bottom-content">
    <div class="size">
        <div class="content1">
            <img src="img/book.png" alt="over ons" class="footer-icon">
            <h2>Over "E.R.D. Easy"</h2>
            <p>Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus.
                Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in,
                viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum.
                Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget
                dui.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="content2">
            <img src="img/certificaat-icon.png" alt="Certificaat" class="footer-icon">
            <h2>Certificaten</h2>
            <img src="img/certificaat.png" class="certificaat" alt="Certificaat">
        </div>
        <div class="content3">
            <img src="img/about-us.png" alt="Contact" class="footer-icon">
            <h2>Contact</h2>
            <p>E.R.D. Easy<br>
                Fahrenheitstraat 45-47<br>
                6716 BR Ede (Holland)<br><br>
                [T] +31 318 64 18 30 <br>
                [E] info@ERD_Easy.nl
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="copyright_bottom">
    <p class="centered_different">@copy <?php echo date("Y"); ?> E.R.D. Easy International BV.
        <a href="sitemap.php" class="sitemap">Sitemap</a></p>
</div>
```

Real CSS:

```
footer {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 0 0 0;
    background-color: rgba(235, 103, 12, 0.1);
}

.bottom-content .content1, .bottom-content .content2, .bottom-content .content3 {
    display: table-cell;
    padding: 0.5em 0 1.5em 0;
    vertical-align: top;
    border-spacing: 20px;
}

footer .bottom-content .content1 {
    width: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 1.3em;
}

footer .bottom-content .content2 {
    width: 20%;
    padding: 0.5em 50px 1.5em 80px;
    text-align: center;
}

footer .bottom-content .content3 {
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 1.4em;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 860px) {
    footer .bottom-content .content1 {
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 90%;
        padding: 30px 0;
        display: block;
        border-bottom: 1px rgba(235, 103, 12, 0.1) solid
    }

    footer .bottom-content .content2 {
        width: 49%;
        padding: 30px 0 0 0;
        display: inline-block;
    }

    footer .bottom-content .content3 {
        width: 49%;
        padding: 30px 0 30px 0;
        display: inline-block;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    .bottom-content .content1, .bottom-content .content2, .bottom-content .content3 {
        display: block;
    }
    footer .bottom-content .content1 {
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 90%;
        padding: 30px 0;
    }

    footer .bottom-content .content2 {
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 90%;
        padding: 30px 0;
    }

    footer .bottom-content .content3 {
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 90%;
        padding: 30px 0;
    }
}

.footer-icon {
    margin-top: 5px;
}

footer .bottom-content p {
    padding-top: 0;
    text-align: center;
}

footer .bottom-content h2 {
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    text-align: center;
}

footer .bottom-content a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

footer .bottom-content li {
    list-style: none;
    margin-left: 1.5em;
    text-align: center;
}

footer .bottom-content ol {
    display: table-cell;
}

footer p {
    color: #414141;

}

footer .copyright_bottom {
    background: #EEEEEE;
    border-top: 1px solid #CBCACA;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    max-height: 60px;
}
```

Comment: it seems like you didn't set css dimensions (width and height) for html and body selectors

Comment: I do have `html, body  {width: 100%; height: 100%; min-height: 100%;}` in my css

Comment: it could be great if you'd show html code of a page

Comment: @Banzay I will put the real css and html in to then, I made a bit of example because I thought it would be enough code.

Comment: If to set `display: inline-block;` for all cells and `width:24%` for last two ones, then it looks working well

Comment: Oh thx, I think that worked. 3 days ago I had `display: inline-block` for every cell but I had a problem with the heights being different all the time. But somehow now it does not.